# Cifs mount on Ubuntu machine does not work for symlinks

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, mount, cifs

I am doing a cifs mount but the symlinks are missing in my mount, I am using a command like this

```
sudo mount -t cifs //x.x.x.x/mnt/remote /mnt/local -o username=user
```

Do i missing something in the options i tried -o loop